# Using data-live-app-payload to specify initialization data

Tags: quip, liveapps

I am experimenting with live apps.   I can build the hello world sample app.  I noticed that the app does not maintain the state, and so I fixed that with these additions

```
static getProperties() {
    return {
        isHighlighted: "boolean"
    };
}
getIsHighlghted = () => this.get("isHighlighted") as boolean

setIsHighlghted = (value: boolean) => this.set("isHighlighted", value)

getActions() {
    return {
        onToggleHighlight: () => {
            this.setIsHighlghted(!this.getIsHighlghted());
            this.notifyListeners();
        },
    };
}
```

Now I would like to be able to specify this value when creating a Quip document.

When I send a URL encoded form with this content

```
<div
  data-live-app-id='NTa9jAYFIBe'
  data-live-app-payload='{/"isHighlighted/": false}'
</div>
```

I get an internal server error failure.   Without the data-live-app-payload attribute it will insert the live app.  I have played with various escaping of the double quotes.  Note, data-live-app-payload='' does not produce an internal server error but data-live-app-payload='{}' does produce the internal server error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it produces an error and that you've narrowed it down to the payload param is encouraging - finding the content of that error may be enlightening, (using the developer console) - but at first glance, the encoding you've posted (I noticed you mentioned you tried a few) won't work.

I would expect this to work:

```
<div
  data-live-app-id="NTa9jAYFIBe"
  data-live-app-payload="{\"isHighlighted\": false}"
</div>
```

Some other context:

- The payload is just parsed as [json](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), so it must use double quotes. If you pass string values, they'll need to be quoted as well.
- The backslash before each quote "escapes" it - this means when you parse the payload, they will be removed. Forward slashes will be interpreted literally, meaning that whoever reads the payload will read the string `{/"isHighlighted/": false}`, which is invalid JSON.
- In theory, you could use single quotes and omit the escaping characters. However, I don't remember if there are assumptions around the formatting in the parsing code that could cause issues there. If you want to try it, you'd instead use:

```
<div
  data-live-app-id='NTa9jAYFIBe'
  data-live-app-payload='{"isHighlighted": false}'
</div>
```

Because the double quotes are not in a double quoted string, they need not be escaped.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Jesse, for getting back to me.  I checked my slash direction and I had it like your example.   I also tried with the single quotes and no slashes and that also gave the same error.   I feel like I'm missing some code that publishes the schema.   I noticed that some of the samples have a json schema document that isn't made by the cli starter application.   I also added the GetProperties after my initial publish, so maybe I should delete the app and republish?  I'll try that.

Comment: No luck with a republish.   Also the sample app at https://github.com/jesseditson/jeopardy-live-app does the same thing.   As does creating a JS sample instead of a TS one.

I noticed that in the jeopardy live app you can export the settings and these settings have a data_version.   I tried using the "data_version" and "data" in the payload settings but that wasn't accepted either.

Comment: I think that’s about as good as I can do, having left Salesforce over a year ago and this project long before then. It’s probable that Quip has regressed or that there is a documentation gap around schemas. I’d explore the latter or try getting help from a current employee. Good luck!

Comment: No worries, I really appreciate you even taking a look.

Comment: I have a small update.  When using the "Kanban Board" Live App that is pre-published to a new Quip site, I can use the data-live-app-payload successfully.   When I took the source code for "Kanban Board" from https://github.com/quip/quip-apps, changed the app-id, built and republished, the live app behaves the same as the stock one but any attempt to use data-live-app-payload attribute fails with the 500 error again.